# How to build java project using Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I am using maven version 3.0.4.I am beginner in maven.I created a Hello world Java project using eclipse.

Now using maven I want to make a executable jar of it and run it.I am not getting how to do.
I also googled for it but what I got is how to create a java project not how to build an existing a java project.

Help me out.

Comment: You could follow the steps in [Maven in 5 minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) This tells you how to build a *Hello World* application using maven.

Answer (score 1):

Download the Maven eclipse Sonatype plugin, and create a Maven project from there.

Use the default Java project archetype usually provided in the list of available archetypes. Upon project creation you will be given a pom.xml.

With the Maven Eclipse plugin, you can build from Eclipse IDE, again the process is simple through build configuration. You will be able to see Maven build configs from there, the build command for Java project should be clean build. (Off my mind) by default, the build e.g. a JAR would be placed in the target folder after successful build.

For existing projects that need to be converted to Maven, you will have to hand create a pom.xml descriptor if you are not using the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to tweak the jar plugin:

http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about an executable jar you mean either ueber-jar or are you talking about creating a shellscript/batch for running you jar file. There are two options for this approach. You can take a look at the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) or take a look at the [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/). Furthermore i recommend to read [Books about Maven](http://sonatype.com/Support/Books/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [Maven Shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) plugin to build and executable jar.
Just add following to your `pom.xml`

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>org.sonatype.haven.HavenCli</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Having added it, fire following command:

```
mvn clean package
```

After successful build you can see a executable jar of your project in `target` folder of you project.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

project->run as->maven build->goals->package ....click to run it will work with eclipse